# British hyphenation in plain LuaTeX

Tags: luatex, hyphenation, plain-tex, eplain

In plain LuaTeX, how do I get British rather than American hyphenation?

```
\input eplain
\beginpackages
\usepackage{showhyphens}
\endpackages

In plain TeX, how do I get British rather than American hyphenation?
In plain TeX, how do I get British rather than American hyphenation?
In plain TeX, how do I get British rather than American hyphenation?
In plain TeX, how do I get British rather than American hyphenation?

\bye
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

showhyphens is a luatex package so I assume that you want to use plain with luatex. In this case this will work:

```
\input eplain
\uselanguage{british}
\beginpackages
\usepackage{showhyphens}
\endpackages

In plain TeX, how do I get British rather than American hyphenation?
In plain TeX, how do I get British rather than American hyphenation?
In plain TeX, how do I get British rather than American hyphenation?
In plain TeX, how do I get British rather than American hyphenation?

\bye
```

Comment: beware `\uselanguage{british}` works because it has been defined in `etex.src`, on top of which `luatex.fmt` was built. True `Plain` TeX or `eplain` do not have multilingual support out of the box.